# Pushing JSON data into array of objects ANGULAR

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, angular6

```js
private contacts: Array < Contact > = [{
  first_name: "Darko",
  last_name: "Lesevic",
  email: ["darko@test.com", "najjaci@test.com"],
  phone: [123456789, 123456789, 123456789],
  photo: "",
  id: 1
}, ];


getContactsJSON(): Observable < IContact[] > {
  return this.http.get < IContact[] > ("/assets/data/contacts.json");
};
//I want to combine these two 
getAllContacts(): Observable < IContact[] > {
  return of(this.contacts);
};
```

I want to put JSON data to contacts array because i'm making CRUD app, but don't know how, please help me. [Here is my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DUXp.png) and [here is my JSON data and class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOftb.png). I want to keep data from JSON and from my own class is that possible?

Comment: Are you trying to push some value to JSON content file fetched from a path? Is that what you are trying?

Comment: I'm trying to push JSON data from my file to array called contacts and then use this combine data from contacts to display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to subscribe to your API request and apply result to your array:

```
this.getContactsJSON.subscribe(s=> {
    this.contacts = s;
    console.log(this.contacts); // you can check your array `this.contacts`
})
```

Comment: @Darko what do you mean by not working? The data is not come?

Comment: There is a lot of errors, it's like JSON data won't go to array of objects

Comment: @Darko could you create a stackblitz example?